# How to get matching row indices from a pandas query?

Tags: python, pandas

Applying a pandas query essentially returns a dataframe that matches the query. I am wondering how one can also retrieve the raw matching row indices (alternatively boolean array)? In particular for dataframes that do have a custom index and therefore do not allow the raw indices to be extracted from the dataframe itself.

```
    Col1
R1     4
R2     5
R3     6
R4     7
```

df.query("Col1 > 5") returns

```
    Col1
R3     6
R4     7
```

The desired output are however the corresponding row indices = [2,3]

Is there any chance to easily retrieve the raw indices with a query without using a secondary compare step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the index after `df.query` with [get_indexer](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html):

```
[*df.index.get_indexer(df.query("Col1 > 5").index)]
```

Or:

```
[*df.index.get_indexer(df.index[df['Col1']>5])]
```

---

```
[2, 3]
```